HK Vision Cameras API with Node.JS
can you help me, please?
I have a problem when making a request for minutes with the hkvision camera.
This is my request, when requesting certain minutes of a video, it returns a batch of complete videos where those minutes that I requested are found, it does not always happen and it is very rare that it happens, so it returns this as a result, when obtaining the playbackURI of each video of each iteration since there can be two videos or more, it downloads all those videos, the problem is that I did tests with a particular video and when giving it the static minutes, it brings me the entire complete video as in the main request. example
I want a video from 10:00:00 to 10:01:59
<CMSearchDescription><searchID>53C8FB29-3865-4A85-8A7A-B08A94E52C0B</searchID>
            <trackList><trackID>3301</trackID></trackList><timeSpanList><timeSpan>
            <startTime>2024-06-06T10:00:00Z</startTime><endTime>2024-06-06T10:01:59Z</endTime>
            </timeSpan></timeSpanList><maxResults>100</maxResults><searchResultPostion>0</searchResultPostion><metadataList>
            <metadataDescriptor>//recordType.meta.std-cgi.com</metadataDescriptor></metadataList></CMSearchDescription>

It shows me two channels, one with 1 large video and the other with two videos, which right there are two videos that make up that minute, a piece of one and the other piece of the other.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<CMSearchResult version="2.0" xmlns="http://www.isapi.org/ver20/XMLSchema">
    <searchID>{53c8fb29-3865-4a85-8a7a-b08a94e52c0b}</searchID>
    <responseStatus>true</responseStatus>
    <responseStatusStrg>OK</responseStatusStrg>
    <numOfMatches>2</numOfMatches>
    <matchList>
        <searchMatchItem>
            <sourceID>{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}</sourceID>
            <trackID>3301</trackID>
            <timeSpan>
                <startTime>2024-06-06T09:24:10Z</startTime>
                <endTime>2024-06-06T10:01:21Z</endTime>
            </timeSpan>
            <mediaSegmentDescriptor>
                <contentType>video</contentType>
                <codecType>H.264-BP</codecType>
                <playbackURI>rtsp://192.168.1.251:80/Streaming/tracks/3301/?starttime=20240606T092410Z&amp;endtime=20240606T100121Z&amp;name=00000000124000200&amp;size=52022404</playbackURI>
                <lockStatus>unlock</lockStatus>
                <name>00000000124000200</name>
            </mediaSegmentDescriptor>
            <metadataMatches>
                <metadataDescriptor>recordType.meta.hikvision.com/timing</metadataDescriptor>
            </metadataMatches>
        </searchMatchItem>
        <searchMatchItem>
            <sourceID>{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}</sourceID>
            <trackID>3301</trackID>
            <timeSpan>
                <startTime>2024-06-06T10:01:21Z</startTime>
                <endTime>2024-06-06T11:49:26Z</endTime>
            </timeSpan>
            <mediaSegmentDescriptor>
                <contentType>video</contentType>
                <codecType>H.264-BP</codecType>
                <playbackURI>rtsp://192.168.1.251:80/Streaming/tracks/3301/?starttime=20240606T100121Z&amp;endtime=20240606T114926Z&amp;name=00000000126000000&amp;size=161019344</playbackURI>
                <lockStatus>unlock</lockStatus>
                <name>00000000126000000</name>
            </mediaSegmentDescriptor>
            <metadataMatches>
                <metadataDescriptor>recordType.meta.hikvision.com/timing</metadataDescriptor>
            </metadataMatches>
        </searchMatchItem>
    </matchList>
</CMSearchResult>```

When I iterate over each element, it downloads the videos of each batch, I did tests but it doesn't work if I dynamically pass the value of the starttime and the endtime to download each video, I did individual tests of the minutes I want in postman and it doesn't respect the minutes the entire video of each batch continues to be downloaded


example

Time that i want 10:00:00 to 10::01:59
rtsp original what brings me the request:

<playbackURI>rtsp://192.168.1.251:80/Streaming/tracks/3301/?starttime=20240606T092410Z&amp;endtime=20240606T100121Z&amp;name=00000000124000200&amp;size=52022404</playbackURI>

rtsp that I want:

<downloadRequest><playbackURI>rtsp://192.168.1.251:80/Streaming/tracks/3301/?starttime=20240606T100000Z&amp;endtime=20240606T100159Z&amp;name=00000000124000200&amp;size=52022404</playbackURI>

So, if you notice, even if I put it in the startime from 10:00:00 to 10:01:59 it downloads the entire video of the batch, it does not respect the minutes that I want





For now I use postman directly but it still downloads the entire video of the batches where the minute I want is located

